# Loading file after converting to ASCII characters

Tags: external-files, xstring, audio

I am writing a document on phonetics using the `media9` package to include pronunciations of some of the words in the document. The words that are to be pronounced are in Danish, and thus their spellings include the non-ASCII characters `æøå`, which LaTeX has never really been comfortable with. What I need is a command `pronounce{word}`, which writes out `word` in the document and links to the sound file, if one such exists. If `word` includes `æ`, `ø`, `å`, or a space, the command first has to ASCIIfy those characters to `ae`, `oe`, `ae`, and `-` and then link to the sound file with the ASCIIfied name.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,geometry,graphicx,amstext}

\usepackage{media9}

\newcommand\listen[2]{ % links to the file #1, then writes out #2
    \includemedia[
    addresource=#1,
    transparent,
    flashvars={
        source=#1
        &autoPlay=true
        &hideBar=true
    },
    ]{#2}{APlayer.swf}
}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*\asciify[1]{% converts æøå and space to ASCII characters and "-"
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{æ}{ae}[\tempone]%
    \StrSubstitute{\tempone}{ø}{oe}[\temptwo]%
    \StrSubstitute{\temptwo}{å}{aa}[\tempthree]%
    \StrSubstitute{\tempthree}{ }{-}%
}

\newcommand*\pronounce[1]{% the final command that is the issue here
    \IfFileExists{\asciify{#1}.mp3}{% only include the file if it exists
        \listen{\asciify{#1}.mp3}{#1}% ASCIIfy the word, then include the file and write out the original word
    }{%
        #1% else, just write out the word
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\pronounce{være}

\end{document}
```

However, I get lots of errors, primarily from `xstring`. I did try putting `\expandafter`s everywhere, and I did try some of the other expandmodes from `xstring`. Didn't help much though. Anybody who can see the error?

Comment: `\StrSubstitute` is not expandable, so you can't use it in the argument of `\IfFileExists`, for instance. See section 3.2 of the manual. In `\asciify`, you should assign the end result to a control sequence and use that in the place where you are using `\asciify` now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your MWE.

The first is that it looks like you're using the wrong encoding for the non-ASCII characters.

Change

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

to

```
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

`xstring` should not have problems anymore.

The second is that there's a problem of expansion.  The following should work.  But you can get around this by using a macro to store the expansion of the last substitution and calling that macro later.  (This is per the expansion instructions in section 3.2 of the manual.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,geometry,graphicx,amstext}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{media9}
\newcommand\listen[2]{ % links to the file #1, then writes out #2
    \includemedia[
    addresource=#1,
    transparent,
    flashvars={
        source=#1
        &autoPlay=true
        &hideBar=true
    },
    ]{#2}{APlayer.swf}
}

\def\mytemp{}%%
\newcommand*\asciify[1]{% converts æøå and space to ASCII characters and "-"
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{æ}{ae}[\tempone]%
    \StrSubstitute{\tempone}{ø}{oe}[\temptwo]%
    \StrSubstitute{\temptwo}{å}{aa}[\tempthree]%
    \StrSubstitute{\tempthree}{ }{-}[\mytemp]%
}

\newcommand*\pronounce[1]{% the final command that is the issue here
    \asciify{#1}%%
    \IfFileExists{\mytemp.mp3}{% only include the file if it exists
        \listen{\mytemp}{#1}% ASCIIfy the word, then include the file and write out the original word
    }{%
        #1% else, just write out the word
    }%
}

\begin{document}
Hello

\pronounce{være}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact, `latin1` *does* work and is just a less rich alternative to `utf8`. However, your other fix solved everything. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Gaussler  That's interesting because I can't get the MWE to compile using `latin1`.  But, I'm glad to hear that the rest of the answer worked for you.

Comment: Might be because you pasted it into a document that was encoded in `utf8` or something like that. What matters is that everyone is happy. :-)